# How to play sound on a remote machine remotely through an SSH connection

Tags: ssh, audio, remote-connection

For example, I am sitting on a laptop at my work station (Windows with PuTTY). My target is sitting in another room with his own Ubuntu laptop with his own user.

I want to use the program [mpg321](http://mpg321.sourceforge.net) to play a WAV file on *his* machine on his user, by logging in via SSH with my user and executing the mpg321 command.

I have tried using `sudo -u his_username`, normal sudo, no sudo, but for some reason the sound doesn’t play.

Answer (score 1):

Probably to late to get confirmation from the original poster, but likely the reason is that either

1. With ALSA only, the Ubuntu laptop user is logged in, and ALSA has taken exclusive ownership of the audio devices; or
2. With PulseAudio, PulseAudio runs as the logged user on the Ubuntu machine and has taken exclusive ownership of the audio devices; which means a second PulseAudio started as a new user can’t take over.

This is as it should be: The person actually sitting at the machine (or at least the person hat logged in first) should have ownership of the local devices like audio. You can't prank him remotely by suddenly playing sounds on the machine. To enable that, one has to configure some kind of "sound sharing" (there are several ways to do that).

Answer (score -1):

If it's just a simple .wav file, why not use [play](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_play.htm) instead? For a while I had this set up on my (Ubuntu) workstation to play the Star Trek "Red Alert" klaxon if a cron'd script detected a particular (and, sadly, common) failure condition on our production database server. It works quite well!

You may have to `sudo apt-get install sox` if it isn't already on the system. Have fun!